# Prove existence of $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $S \neq \emptyset$ and $S$ bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $S$ contained in $\mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty bounded set. Then there exists monotone sequences $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ is contained in $S$.

How do I prove that $\sup S = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ and $\inf S = \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n$?

Comment: Hopefully I understand your question correctly while editing and somebody will now be willing to answer it!

Comment: Thank  you, you did understand it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is bounded it has a least upper bound, say $U=\sup S$ Thus for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find an element $x\in S$ such that $|x-U|<\epsilon$.

We can generate the sequence $X_n$ as follows. Let for each $n$, let $X_n$ be any element in $S$ that satisfies $|X_n-U|<1/n$ (provided, of course, that the sequence is kept monotone non-decreasing). Then $X_n$ is monotone and bounded (by inclusion in $S$) so it must converge to some limit $L$. Clearly we must have $L\le U$. Suppose that $L<U$. Then $U-L>0$ is a positive number, but we can find an $N$** such that for all $n>N$ we have $$|U-L|=|(U-X_n)+(X_n-L)|\le |X_n-U|+|X_n-L|<{U-L\over 2}+{U-L\over 2}=U-L$$ so we must have $U=L$.

The case of the greatest lower bound would be similar.

**Namely, take $$N=\max\Bigg\{\bigg\lceil{2\over U-L}\bigg\rceil,\;N\,\left({U-L\over 2}\right)\Bigg\}$$ where $N(\epsilon)$ is any $N>0$ such that $|X_n-L|<\epsilon$ when $n>N$.

Comment: For the lower bound do I do exactly the same thing or do I have to switch signs?

Comment: @Ayoshna If you understand the gist of the argument, then just modify it to work for the infimum (the argument will be the same, the details will be slightly different). If not, please let me know what doesn't make sense.